# Python File is Not Being Rewritten Properly

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to rewrite a file in python, and I can't seem to figure out why the file isn't being overwritten. Here is my code:

```
# these are just for this case. 
# These variables come from elsewhere but they will evaluate to these when we hit this point.

command = 'RMDir'
current_dir = '$workingDirectory'

# end variables

product_name_1 = "Product 1"
product_name_2 = "Product 2"
product_name_3 = "Product 3"
product_1_instruction = command + ' \"' + current_dir + '\\' + product_name_1 + '\"\n'
product_2_instruction = command + ' \"' + current_dir + '\\' + product_name_2 + '\"\n'
product_3_instruction = command + ' \"' + current_dir + '\\' + product_name_3 + '\"\n'

file_path = f.name
output = []
f.close()
with open(file_path, 'r+') as f:
    for line in f:
        if product_1_instruction != line \
                and product_2_instruction != line \
                and product_3_instruction != line:
            output.append(line)
    f.writelines(output)
```

Prior to this code we have written a file with `f`. Now, I am trying to close it and reopen it to overwrite, loop through the lines, and if a line matches one of my instruction strings, exclude it from `output`. Once we're done looping, I want to overwrite the contents of `f` with the lines in `output`, but for some reason it is not happening.

I have verified that my equality checks are going through, and that `output` is correctly loaded with the right values, but it just seems like the file itself is not being overwritten with the right content.

Comment: Open 2 files, A and B, where A is the original file, and B is a temp file.  While reading A, process and then dump your output to B.  After you finish and close A, you can Close B.  Then delete A and rename B to A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first read your file, then open it in write mode to overwrite it:

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if product_1_instruction != line \
                and product_2_instruction != line \
                and product_3_instruction != line:
            output.append(line)
with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(output)
```

don't use read/write mode for text/csv files. It's more useful for binary/fixed format files.

note that a list comprehension is more pythonic instead of your loop:

```
forbidden = [product_1_instruction,product_2_instruction,product_3_instruction]
output = [line for line in f if line not in forbidden]
```

(make `forbidden` a `set` if you have a lot of products, it'll make lookups faster)

Comment: This was it, reading to get the output and then opening it for writing after worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: And just as a follow up, the list comprehension worked as well. I'm still learning python, this helps a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

simple use `w` it will delete the old file and create new.

```
with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
    ...
```

Comment: That was my initial try, and I get this error when I use that:
[ERROR] Error while generating script: File not open for reading

Comment: yes, that's the way. But your answer isn't clear about that. OP, for instance, thought that you're suggesting to _replace_ the open in reading by that.